# Show output of Python script in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, image-processing, tkinter

I am new to python & requesting help from experts in this community. I am trying to display the output of the following script in my Tkinter GUI. I have followed many solutions provided on the StackOverflow, but unfortunately, I am unable to implement those solutions in my code. I need help in displaying the output of the following script in my Tkinter GUI. So I can display the output in a Tkinter widget.

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

class Difference_Button(Sample_Button, Button):
   def on_click_diff_per_button(self, diff_per):
      threshold = 0.8  # set threshold
       resultsDirectory = 'Data/Differece_images'
       sourceDirectory = os.fsencode('Data/images')
       templateDirectory = os.fsencode('Data/Sample_images')
       detectedCount = 0

       for file in os.listdir(sourceDirectory):
           filename = os.fsdecode(file)
           if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"):

               print(filename)

               img = cv2.imread('Data/images/' + filename)
               im_grayRef = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

               for templateFile in os.listdir(templateDirectory):
                   templateFilename = os.fsdecode(templateFile)

                   if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
                       Sample_image = cv2.imread('Data/Sample_images/' + templateFilename, 0)
                       #im_graySam = cv2.cvtColor(Sample_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                       cv2.waitKey(0)
                       w, h = Sample_image.shape[::-1]

                       score = cv2.matchTemplate(im_grayRef,Sample_image,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
                       #diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
                       cv2.waitKey(0)
                       diffvalue = print("Image similarity %ge of_" + filename + "_&_" + templateFilename + "_is", score * 100)
                       # res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
                       loc = np.where(score >= threshold)

                       if (len(loc[0])):
                           detectedCount = detectedCount + 1
                           for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
                               cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
                       cv2.imwrite(resultsDirectory + '/diff_per_' + filename + '.jpg', img)
                       Difference_per_label.config(text='diff_per ' + filename + "_&_" + templateFilename + ' saved')
                       print('diff_per ' + filename + "_&_" + templateFilename + ' saved')
                           # break
               #print('detected positive ' + str(detectedCount))
               continue
           else:
               continue


if __name__ == '__main__':


   root = tk.Tk()
   root.title('Image GUI')
   root.geometry('1280x960')
   os.makedirs('Data/Differece_images', exist_ok=True)
   pw_left = tk.Frame(root, relief='ridge', borderwidth=4)
   pw_left.pack(side='left',anchor='nw')
   pw_left = tk.Frame(root, relief='ridge', borderwidth=4)
   pw_left.pack(side='left', anchor='nw')
   frame7 = tk.Frame(pw_left, bd=2, relief="ridge")
   frame7.pack()
   difference_button = Difference_Button(root, frame7)
   Difference_per_label = tk.Label(frame7, text='print', width=40, bg='white', height = '5')
   Difference_per_label.pack(fill=tk.X)
   Diff_label = tk.Label(frame7, textvariable= 'diffvalue', width=40, bg='white', height = '5')
   Diff_label.pack(fill=tk.X)
   Difference_button = tk.Button(frame7, text='Difference',
                                 command=lambda: difference_button.on_click_diff_per_button(Difference_per_label))
   Difference_button.pack(side='bottom', padx=5, pady=5)
   root.mainloop()
```

**Help Required section:**

- How to display the below command output in Tkinter `diffvalue = print("Image similarity %ge of_" + filename + "_&_" + templateFilename + "_is", score * 100)`
- The below command is not displaying all
  the result from starting to end. It is showing only the last
  output. `Difference_per_label.config(text='diff_per ' + filename + "_&_" +    templateFilename + ' saved')`
- Once it is done I want to apply **try except** logic for the statement corrected label i.e currently displaying as  `diffvalue = print("Image similarity %ge of_" + filename + "_&_" + templateFilename + "_is", score * 100)` & `print('diff_per ' + filename + "_&_" + templateFilename + ' saved')` so that if nothing is present in the folder it will throw exception command.

**Note:**

- *Image similarity %ge of_*: Fixed
- *filename*: Variable
- *_&_*: Fixed
- *templateFilename*:Variable
- *_is*:Fixed
- **score*100**: Varies according to the difference percentage

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Req: Please close the answer only if all the solutions of **Help Required section:** is resolved.

Comment: `print()` only sends text on screen. It never returns displayed text. To assign to variable use it without `print()` - `diffvalue = "Image ..."`

Comment: if you want to append text to `Label` then you have to get old text from `Label`, append new text to old text, put all again to `Label`

Comment: BTW: we close question only if question is useless (ie. there is other question with solution, or there is not enough information to resolve it, etc.) , not when all problems are resolved.

Comment: `else:continue` and `continue` at the end of `if` is useless if there is no other code after `conitunue` in loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print()` only sends text on screen. It never returns displayed text.
To assign to variable use it without `print()` - ie.

```
diffvalue = "Image similarity %ge of_{}_&_{}_is {}".format(filename, templateFilename, score * 100)
```

And now you can display text in `Label` or `Text` or `Listbox`

---

To append text to `Label` you have to get old text from `Label`, concatenate new text to old text, and put all again to `Label` - ie

```
new_text = 'diff_per {}_&_{} saved'.format(filename, templateFilename)
Difference_per_label["text"] = Difference_per_label["text"] + "\n" + new_text
```

or shorter wiht `+=`

```
Difference_per_label["text"] += "\n" + new_text
```

---

Because `tkinter` (and other GUIs) doesn't update widget in window when you change text in label but when it ends function executed by Button and it returns to mainloop so you may have to use `root.update()` after changing text in Label to force `mainloop()` to redraw windgets in window.

---

To throw exception you need `raise()`, not `try/except` which is used to catch exception.

And to test if there is no file you would have to get all data from `os.listdir()` as list, filter list with `endswith()` and check if list is empty.

```
import os

sourceDirectory = '.'

all_files = os.listdir(sourceDirectory)
all_files = [os.fsdecode(file) for file in all_files]
#all_files = map(os.fsdecode, all_files)
all_files = [file for file in all_files if file.lower().endswith((".jpg",".png"))]

#if len(all_files) == 0:
if not all_files:
    raise(Exception("No Files"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. ```diffvalue = "Image similarity %ge of_{}_&_{}_is {}".format(filename, templateFilename, score * 100)``` and ```Difference_per_label["text"] += "\n" + new_text``` was very helpful from your side. Can you please help me little more with **How to update widget in window?** and **How to test if there is no file in the directory?**

Comment: I added code which check if there is no images and raise error

Comment: what widget do you want to update? To update text in Label you have `Difference_per_label["text"]  = ...`. Other widgets similar `widget["variable"] = value` or `widget.config(variable=value)`. If you run it in long running function then you may need `root.update()` after every `widget.config(variable=value)`. Tkinter doesn't do it automatically in running function but after function to redraw all widgeet at once and not flicker,

Comment: Thanks for your support. It was very informative. :) have a nice day.